# Protecting a circuit when working voltage is close to the absolute maximum

Tags: surge-protection

I designed a step down converter using [WEBENCH](https://webench.ti.com/power-designer/switching-regulator). It takes 8-24V DC input and outputs 5V. The basic design works fine, but I learned from [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/545179/hot-plugging-power-kills-switch-mode-converter) about why it died when I connected it to a 24V power supply that was already turned on.

[image: Step down converter schematic]

I did some experiments with the dead board. Here's an oscilloscope trace showing the max voltage when the 24V PSU is powered up and the input capacitors charge:

[image: Oscilloscope trace showing significant ringing and 75V max voltage]

A peak of 75V, even for a few microseconds, is far above the 26V absolute maximum rating of the [TPS51396A](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps51396a.pdf?ts=1694880535502).

For comparison, here is the trace if the circuit is powered up with the cable connected (note different X and Y scale).

[image: Oscilloscope trace showing a steady rise to working voltage of 24V]

The test setup for these traces is shown below:

[image: Test setup showing an oscilloscope, power supply and the device under test]

Instead of a probe I used crocodile clips - positive across the incoming supply and GND at the output (which is connected to the inner ground plane). The switch connects the output of the power supply to the input of the converter.

The [application note](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/an88f.pdf) referenced in [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/545192/30062) is useful. I avoided aluminium electrolytic capacitors because they are typically less robust (the PCB is not in a case), but could add one to a future revision of the board.

A TVS diode seems like a sensible choice but I am struggling to find a suitable option because the working voltage of 24V is very close to the 26V absolute maximum rating. A similar problem is described in [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/357159/how-to-protect-againt-surges-if-working-and-maximum-voltage-are-too-close), but in that case there is 12V between the working voltage and absolute maximum.

For future revisions I could add a general purpose diode for reverse polarity protection, which would give slightly wider voltage range due to the diode drop.

Is it possible to find a TVS that will clamp these excess voltages, or should I be looking for a different solution?

Comment: 2V margin is way too small. Operating continuously near absolute max is a serious reliability hit, even if you never exceed the rating.

Comment: Please show your measurement setup for detecting 75 V peak.

Comment: @JohnDoty the recommended operating conditions include a max of 24V - is reliability still impacted when running within those specs?

Comment: @winny test setup shown. Advice on improving this would be welcomed. However, it's almost certainly what killed the device regardless of the peak voltage.

Comment: Yes.You want some margin.

Comment: You need a proper 10x probe with ground spring to measure it. Overshoot is much less than you have measured. But the elephant in the room is lack of voltage margin anyway.

Comment: Related: technique for using oscilloscope probe ground rings for low inductance measurement - https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/136123/how-do-you-attach-an-oscilloscope-ground-spring

Comment: Thanks @winny - I repeated with a 10X probe but can't find the sprung clip, so made a custom one out of solid copper wire. I see the same results, which I think suggests the probing technique is not good.

Comment: I can get an identical Mean Well LRS-200-15 at 15V instead of 24V - will need to redo calculations for max current in the cabling but reducing the maximum voltage might be the right answer. This would give 11V of margin and potentially allow better input protection.

Comment: I wonder how usable a TL431 would be as surge-suppression. Can't say I've ever tried it; it might not be fast enough.

Comment: @David When you're using Webench, you can select "Automotive" in the "IC Features" section on the left. That could give you a regulator with a better input voltage range and better transient tolerance. For example, the [LMR38010-Q1 4.2-V to 80-V, 1-A, Automotive, Synchronous SIMPLE SWITCHER](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmr38010-q1.pdf?ts=1695053545657). N.B. I am not an electronics engineer.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewMorton - that part does not have enough output current but a useful hint for future.

Comment: @David There are other automotive-rated parts with higher currents available. *not have enough output current* - don't keep us guessing!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it possible to find a TVS that will clamp these excess voltages, or should I be looking for a different solution?

Sure, Zener diodes with Zener voltages in the 25 V to 26 V range exist and aren't expensive:  https://www.digikey.de/short/fp404m81

**But**.

1. A diode's Zener voltage *heavily* depends on temperature. (All components are thermosensors, some are also useful for other things… this is *extremely* true for diodes in high reverse bias.)
2. It's questionable whether the diode will breakthrough first, or the semiconductor junction that becomes conductive inside your regulator IC. In the end, both are starting to conduct for the same reason.

So:

It would be wise to limit the inrush current. A simple series resistor would do – of course at the expense of wasting power. You could, however, be smart about things, like putting an P-channel MOSFET in parallel with it, and only pulling the gate low as long as the supply voltage is sufficiently below 26 V. You'd waste a bit additional power as long as you're operating "dangerously close", but my guess is that these are the times where you don't have to care about power efficiency as much, anyways.

Comment: No huge concerns about power efficiency - the step down is required to lower the total current in the wires leading to the devices.  This TI paper on inrush current looks helpful: https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva670a/slva670a.pdf?ts=1694956747966

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that can squeeze into that margin is a surge stopping IC:
https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/product-selector-card/Surge-Stoppers.pdf

This should work, but probably isn’t great system design.  If you can respecify the converter you can go back to the cheaper and simpler passive solutions already mentioned (TVS).

Comment: Thanks. I can likely respecify the input voltage and decrease to 15V, giving 11V of margin to the absolute maximum. This is at the expense of additional cabling to accommodate the maximum current.

Answer (score 2):

If hot plugging is a major concern, you could look at using an N-FET, sense resistor and hot-swap controller. This will also give you to inrush limiting, overload protection and reset control. There are lots of parts available, but the LTC4368 is a good starting point.

Alternatively, add a large high ESR electrolytic on the input.  This will tend to damp the ringing when power is applied.